# Analysis of MongoDB and Badges system

Tags: java, mongodb, social-networking, badge, nosql

We are developing a system which does some statistical analysis based on social networking data, eg: tweets, status updates etc. I was thinking to store user related information on a relational database (MySQL) and social networks data on a nosql database (MongoDB). Is this a correct approach? Or is it better to use MongoDB for the whole system? Please share your thoughts on usage of NoSQL databases for such a system.

Also i need a badges system integrated to this one to distribute badges on more contributions by users. Are there any open source or commercial badges systems available? So far, based on my searches, i found only mozilla open badges project which i don't think is a perfect fit for us.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I just finished spending a solid year with Mongo and I'm not sure it would be a good fit for you with statistical analysis.

If I were you I'd want to use only one database technology. All MySQL or all Mongo. Doing both with create a lot of headaches.

MongoDB is great for quick and dirty data modeling and having heterogeneous documents living in one collection. In other words, you don't have to manage the schema so actively, which can be really nice.

The problem with MongoDB is in the analysis you would want to do. While I believe the new aggregation framework solves a lot of the problems Mongo used to have with adhoc reports and queries, the framework runs incredibly slow compared to a normal relational database like MySQL.

Lots of people scale MySQL to very large systems, so I would recommend sticking with MySQL due to the query language flexibility and the speed of running more complex queries.